# Ajax/JSON only returns 1 result from PHP/SQL file - can't find the solution

Tags: php, jquery, sql, json, ajax

I am trying to get receive data based on AJAX/JSON returns an array from another file where i have a PHP While loop, but it only returns 1 data and nothing else. I have 11 rows to show.

I have tried to search on google, youtube and numerous other places for what i am doing wrong. I am using latest version of jQuery and jQuery UI. I have tried to read the console.log data in different places and i have also tried with different names. Still nothing.

HTML:

```
$HTMLOUT .= '<div class="container">';
    $HTMLOUT .= '<h4 class="text-center mt-3">Quick Search</h4>';
    $HTMLOUT .= '<form>';
        $HTMLOUT .= '<div class="form-row py-3">';
            $HTMLOUT .= '<div class="col-12 col-md-3">';
                $HTMLOUT .= '<select id="AJAX_ID_category" class="custom-select custom-select-sm">';
                    //$HTMLOUT .= '';
                $HTMLOUT .= '</select>';
            $HTMLOUT .= '</div>';
            $HTMLOUT .= '<div class="col-12 col-md-3">';
                $HTMLOUT .= '<select id="AJAX_ID_brand" class="custom-select custom-select-sm">';
                    //$HTMLOUT .= '';
                $HTMLOUT .= '</select>';
            $HTMLOUT .= '</div>';
            $HTMLOUT .= '<div class="col-12 col-md-3">';
                $HTMLOUT .= '<select id="AJAX_ID_model" class="custom-select custom-select-sm">';
                    //$HTMLOUT .= '';
                $HTMLOUT .= '</select>';
            $HTMLOUT .= '</div>';
            $HTMLOUT .= '<div class="col-12 col-md-3">';
                $HTMLOUT .= '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="FORM_NAME_submit">Quick Search</button>';
            $HTMLOUT .= '</div>';
        $HTMLOUT .= '</div>';
    $HTMLOUT .= '</form>';
$HTMLOUT .= '</div>';
```

PHP:

```
// (index.php) = Quick Search > Categories
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "get_categories") {
    //header('Content-Type: application/json'); // not needed, but a good idea to set!
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","backup_job_v1_www_oppulense_com_backup_1");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_category";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $json = array();
    $json['ARRAY_get_categories']['count_total_returns'] = 0;
    //while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $json['ARRAY_get_categories']['id'] = $row['category_id'];
        $json['ARRAY_get_categories']['name'] = (!$row['category_name'] == NULL ? $row['category_name'] : "None");
        $json['ARRAY_get_categories']['count_total_returns']++;
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}

// (index.php) = Quick Search > Brands
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "get_brands_from") {
    header('Content-Type: application/json'); // not needed, but a good idea to set!
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","backup_job_v1_www_oppulense_com_backup_1");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM vehicle_brand WHERE v_b_FK_category_id = ".$_POST['id_cat']."";
    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $json = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $json['ARRAY_get_brands']['id'] = $row['brand_id'];
        $json['ARRAY_get_brands']['name'] = (!$row['brand_name'] == NULL ? $row['brand_name'] : "None");
    }
    echo json_encode($json);
}

// (index.php) = Quick Search > Models
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == "get_models_from") {
    //header('Content-Type: application/json'); // not needed, but a good idea to set!
    // Models
}
```

jQuery:

```
var base_route = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
    get_categories();
});
function get_categories() {
    var items = "<option selected value=''>SELECT CATEGORY</option>";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_route+"inc/ajax-handler.php",
        data: {action:"get_categories"},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(response){
            if(response != null){
                $.each(response, function(index, value){
                    console.log(index);
                    console.log(value);
                    if(value.name != 'None'){
                        items+="<option value='"+value.id+"'>"+value.name+"</option>";
                    }
                });
                $("#AJAX_ID_category").html(items);
            }
        }
    });
}
function get_brands_from(category){
    var items = "<option selected value=''>SELECT BRAND</option>";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_route+"inc/ajax-handler.php",
        data: {action:"get_brands_from", id_cat:category},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(response){
            if(response != null){
                $.each(response, function(index, value){
                    console.log(index);
                    console.log(value);
                    if(value.name != 'None'){
                        items+="<option value='"+value.id+"'>"+value.name+"</option>";
                    }
                });
                $("#AJAX_ID_brand").html(items);
                $("#AJAX_ID_brand").selectmenu('refresh', true);
            }
            //$("#AJAX_ID_model").html("<option selected value=''>SELECT MODEL</option>");
            //$("#AJAX_ID_model").selectmenu('refresh', true);
        }
    });
}
function get_models_from(category, brand){
    var items = "<option value=''>Select a Model</option>";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_route+"inc/ajax-handler.php",
        data: {action:"get_models_from", id_cat:category, id_brand:brand},
        dataType: 'json', success:function(response){
            if (response != null){
                $.each(response, function(index, value){
                    console.log(index);
                    console.log(value);
                    if(item.name.indexOf(' in ') < 0){
                        items+="<option value='"+value.name.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase()+"'>"+value.name+"</option>";
                    }
                });
                $("#AJAX_ID_model").html(items);
                $("#AJAX_ID_model").selectmenu('refresh', true);
            }
        }
    });
}
$( "#AJAX_ID_category" ).selectmenu({
    change: function( event, ui ){
        var category = $(this).val();
        get_brands_from(category);
    }
});
$( "#AJAX_ID_brand" ).selectmenu({
    change: function( event, ui ){
        var brand = $(this).val();
        var category = $("#sel_category").val();
        get_models_from(category, brand);
    }
});
$( "#AJAX_ID_model" ).selectmenu({
    change: function( event, ui ){
        var model = $(this).val();
        window.location.href = location.href+"car/"+model
    }
});
```

I have 3 different select/options html boxes. I wish to extracts categories, brand and vehicles. On the first dropdown, categories, i wish to just extract every category there is by running AJAX. I am un-able to do so. It gives me 1 result and does not return anything else, even tho i know i have 11 different rows in the MySQL database (PhpMyAdmin).

After the selected category, i wish to show the options in the next select line, based on the ID from the categories and once the brand-category now has been selected, i would like to show vehicles, of course based on both ID's. In which case is now from categories AND brand id.

Once the vehicle has been selected, i would then like the submit button to appear in a form of fade-in via jquery.

When the submit button has been hit, the user should be redirected to the page (details.php?id=x).

Please note that the code is still in-complete, i have just been struggling with this part of the code for a while now and still do. Hope you can help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each iteration of your loops to store the data are just overwriting the same set of array elements, I'll show how the first one can be done, you should be able to work the others out.

Each time it adds the content (in one assignment) using `[]`, I've also use the null coalesce (`??`) to set the name...

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $json['ARRAY_get_categories'][] = ['id' => $row['category_id',
                 'name' => $row['category_name'] ?? "None"];
    $json['ARRAY_get_categories']['count_total_returns']++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i get out all of the sql. However now i have another problem. When i made the cahnges, i got "undefined" and still only 1 in the select menu. Should i change something in the jquery?

Comment: You will now get an array of values back, so your code which displays the menu will need to loop over the options in the `'ARRAY_get_categories'` element.

Comment: ok, but the whole idea is to run everything from jQuery. Sorry, still a little off with the jQuery part. But you say i need to run over with a loop with the array, i get that, but is that not what i am already doing with the "$.each" in jQuery? Or do i misunderstand the purpose of that function?

Comment: What do the `console.log()` lines give you when it is building the output?

Comment: it gives me everything in an array as you would expect. ARRAY_get_categories and then an array with all details. ID's and NAME's. however still in the dropdown menu i only get 1 output and in that output the name and the value is the same. Undefined. Is it somewhere in the jQuery? I know you said i should loop through them but i am by using $.each from what i already understand? Right?

Comment: I think you are doing the each at the wrong level, try `$.each(response.ARRAY_get_categories, function(index, value){`

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that i simply needed to remove the extra array part in the json return php code and then it worked :D - will try your way also, but for now i know it works so thanks! Much needed! :D